# Ethereum Uncles - What if there are conflicts?

Tags: consensus

In questions like here - [In Ethereum, what is an uncle block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39329/in-ethereum-what-is-an-uncle-block) - people are saying that uncles are just being included in some of the next 7 blocks. So far so good.

What if a uncle is conflicting with the corresponding sibling block?

- Is it discarded?
- Can this concept being misused to attack the consensus?
- How often does these conflicts occur?

To me the chance of having conflicts in two sibling blocks seems fairly reasonable, since both miners tend to choose the transactions with the most payout.

Comment: Can someone move it there or are these two different servers

Comment: I have requested a move. A moderator will look at it in due course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncles are included in the block but the transactions in uncles are not applied to the state so even if there are conflicting transactions it's not a problem.

Comment: Uh, this is an option I have not thought about before. *thinkingface*
Are there some resources where I can read more about it?

Comment: @DanielHitzel the most complete and detailed information I've found is in the http://yellowpaper.io. Search for "ommer" keyword.

Comment: I cannot find a keyword "ommer" with Ctrl+F. Did you mistype it?

Comment: @DanielHitzel check section 4.4.2. Holistic Validity. We can assert a block’s validity if and only if it satisfies several conditions: it must be internally
consistent with the **ommer**. Or section 4.4 it has "ommersHash"